# John the Ripper Character Lists

Tags: hash, brute-force, password-cracking, ntlm, john-the-ripper

How is it possible to use or prioritize umlauted characters - ä ö ü ß Ä Ö Ü - whilst brute forcing.

I'm not using any wordlist, only dozens of CPU threads via the following command :

```
./john --fork=64 --format=NT hash.txt
```

Using john-1.8.0-jumbo-1.

Answer (score 3):

When you look at the documentation, you are looking for the terms "character set" and "charset"

> By default, the [Incremental:All] parameters are set to use the full
>   printable US-ASCII character set (95 characters)

The [95 characters](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) do not include umlauts.

But later, the documentation reads:

> If you've got a password file for which you already have a lot of
>   passwords cracked or obtained by other means, and the passwords are
>   unusual, then you may want to generate a new charset file, based on
>   character frequencies from that password file only:
>
> john --make-charset=custom.chr mypasswd

What you do is create a .pot file with the characters you want to include, update your .conf file for a new character set file, then run

```
john --make-charset=custom.chr
```

Comment: Hmm ... sounds great, but in docs we also have : `If you've got some passwords cracked, they are stored in $JOHN/john.pot. The john.pot file is not meant to be human-friendly. You should be using John itself to display the contents of its "pot file" in a convenient format.` So, the question is how can I build my custom.chr? Guess I want it to contain `a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ1234567890`~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':",../<>?`. I would highly appreciate if you help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer is not useful. Running the command shown here just yields `Loaded 0 plaintexts, exiting...`.